# Modulo Result Starting At '1'

Tags: python, modulo

This is a sort of beginner question but I couldn't find a good answer.

I have:

```
self.date = ( self.date + 1 ) % 31
```

So the results start at 0 1 2 3 ... and ends in 29 30 0 1 ....

How do I shift it such that it starts at 1 2 3 4 and results in 30 31 1 2 3 ... with as clean as a syntax as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.date = (self.date % 31) + 1
```

I think this is what you mean.

EDIT: I saw your comment on the other answer, and here's an explanation of what you're doing:

`(self.date % 31)` means to take the value of date and find the remainder when you divide by 31 (which you know). If you use `self.date +1 % 31`, then starting with `date = 0` you will get 1,2,3..30. When `date=30`, it will end up as `30+1 % 31`, or `31 % 31` which is 0.

If you add the 1 after, at `date=30` you will have `30 % 31`, still giving you `30`, then +1 to give the 30,31,1 you want.

Answer (score 1):

Add one:

```
self.date = ((self.date + 1) % 31) + 1
```

Comment: Thanks but your result doesn't starts over again after 30 instead of 31.

Comment: @Jim - I was just using your code and your description of what it does. You were already adding one to `self.date` so I assumed that's what you wanted.